# funcion PHP selectById me devuelve 'root' cuando le paso un $id que no existe

Tags: php

tengo esta funcion **que me devuelve un familiar**.

```
  function familiar_obtenerPorId($id){
    include_once 'procedimientos/conexion.php';

    if ($con) {

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM familiares WHERE id =".$id.";";

       $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

       if ($result) {


          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $usuario = $row;
          }

          if ($usuario) {
            return $usuario;
          }
          else{
            return null;
          }
        } 
    }


    return null;



  }
```

y lo **compruebo de la siguiente manera**:

```
  $result = familiar_obtenerPorId(21);

  var_dump($result);
```

Entonces si le paso un `$id` que existe me retorna sin problema con el `var_dump()`. Pero **si le paso un `$id` que no existe** me retorna : `'root'` en vez de retorname **null** como le indico.

**¿Por que me retorna root y que significa que retorne eso?**

Comment: Puedes mostrarme procedimientos/conexion.php porque creo que por ahí tienes una variable $usuario suelta

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar el código es esta manera:

```
function familiar_obtenerPorId($id){
    include_once 'procedimientos/conexion.php';
    if ($con) {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM familiares WHERE id =".$id.";";

       $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

       if ($result->num_rows>0) { // Si el n de filas que se han encontrado es mayor que 0
           return $result->fetch_row(); // Devuelto la primera (y debería ser la única) fila
       }
       else{ // Si no ha encontrado filas, devuelve null
            return null;
       }
    }
}
```

Ten también en cuenta que en la varible `$usuario` estas guardando la tupla que tiene la información del familiar, no solamente el nombre. Si quieres devolver el nombre: `return $result->fetch_row[X]`, donde X es el index de la columna `nombre` de la tabla `familiares`.

Comment: esto no seria si estuviese usando objetos ?